# When I copy an array, the first array will change when I change a value of the second array?

Tags: java, arrays

In Java for example:

```java
int x[] = {1,2,3,4};
    
int y[] = x;
y[0] = 100;
System.out.println(x[0]);
System.out.println(y[0]);
```

Output:

```
100
100
```

How can I change the values of `int y` without changing values of `int x`?

Comment: You do not copy it. X and y points to the same array

Comment: Even though Java allows you to use `int x[]`, that syntax is discouraged (and IMHO a historic mistake). The general convention is to use `int[] x`, as that is far more clear and readable to most Java programmers.

Answer (score 1):

You are pointing to same array location hence updating one will update the second.

Use clone() method to create copy of the array.

```
    int x[] = {1,2,3,4};
    
    int y[] = x.clone();
    y[0] = 100;
    System.out.println(x[0]);
    System.out.println(y[0]);
```

**Output :**

```
1
100
```

Comment: So there's no benefit in doing what we did before? I mean what is the point of y if I say
int y = x;